# Moving/reordering tabs/page controls by dragging

Tags: delphi, tabs, drag-and-drop

In my program i want to use sdi instead of mdi and i would like to do that by using tabs or page controls, i see microsoft edge/google chrome has very nice tab features for every page

I want to let user drag a tab and change the order of it with animation,

[image: Like the on in the gif file below]

I dont know where to start? Drag and drop? Or should i use a third party component? Or can anyone give me an example for that?

How can i do a tab/page control behave like this to change position? Please give me an example or let me know where to start? What to look/search in?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

There is a 3rd party component called [TChromeTabs](http://www.easy-ip.net/tchrometabs.html) that looks (and behaves) just like Chrome tabs (including the animations).